# How do I get the messages view back in Mail on OS X?

Tags: mail.app, macos

Normally when in the non-classic view in Mail there is list on the left for my mailbox, a list in the middle for my inbox, and a list on the right for the messages contained in a conversation. I don't see the last list on the right. Is there a way to get that pane back, perhaps through an option in the menu? I'm running the last versions of everything (10.11).

Comment: You mean you want to get back the list of messages in a conversation, rather than the scrollable one-after-another view that it is now?

Comment: @timothymh I had 3 panes (mailboxes,inbox,conversation) and now I have 2 (mailboxes,inbox). I want the one that contains the contents of my emails back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've dragged the right edge of the middle list all the way to the right, which then hides the preview of the messages. If you hover your mouse of the right edge of the scroll bar on the right you should get the draggable crosshair mouse pointer. Hold it and drag left and you should get the previews back.

Comment: Thanks. I think I lost the pane when I dragged it while in classic mode. I found that it was easier to bring it back in classic mode first as there at least a small visual indication (1 or 2 pt line with a dot in the middle) when you have dragged the panel far enough to hide it. That indicator isn't present in the default (non-classic) mode.

Comment: Note: You need to drag leftwards for a significant distance before it has any effect. I thought this answer was not working at all because I was just dragging slightly past the scrollbar. Only when I dragged about one third the width of the Mail window did the message pane re-appear.